# Totally Stuck -- Need Models but none available - What to do?

Tags: opengl, models, bmp

So I've got this class where I have to make a simple game in OpenGL.
I want to make space invanders (basically).

So how in the world should I make anything appear on my screen that looks decent at all? :(
I found some code, finally, that let me import a 3DS object. It was sweet I thought and went and put it in a class to make it a little more modular and usable (http://www.spacesimulator.net/tut4_3dsloader.html).

However, either the program I use (Cheetah3d) is exporting the uv map incorrectly and/or the code for reading in a .bmp that ISN'T the one that came with the demo. The image is all weird. Very hard to explain.

So I arrive at my question. What solution should I use to draw objects? Should I honestly expect to spend hours guessing at vertices to make a space invader ship? Then also try to map a decent texture to this object as well? The code I am using draws the untextured object just fine but I can't begin to go mapping the texture to it because I don't know what vertices correspond to what polygons etc.

Thanks SO for any suggestions on what I should do. :D

Answer (score 1):

You could draw textured quads, provided you have a texture loader.

I really wouldn't worry too much about your "uv map" - if you can get your vertices right then you can generally cludge something anyway. That's what I'd do.

Comment: Agreed.  If all you're doing is making a 2D game (which space invaders is) then all you need to do is draw the spaceships as bitmaps (using Photoshop, paint.Net, whatever) and render the spaceships as quads (or two triangles) with the spaceship bitmaps mapped to it (map the image corners to the quad corners).  Then translate/rotate/scale each quad as necessary.

Comment: I am wanting to do Space Invaders with 3D graphics.

Comment: Try finding models here: http://sketchup.google.com/3dwarehouse/search?q=spaceship&styp=m&btnG=Search